# Combining Multiple Select Statements Into One With A Count from Each Select Statement

Tags: t-sql

I have a scenario where a Contact can be an Owner and/or a Builder or neither. The data sits in two separate tables, e.g:

```
SELECT     Contacts.Id, count(Owners.Id) AS [Owner Count]
FROM       Contacts INNER JOIN Owners ON Contacts.Id = Owners.Id
GROUP BY   Contacts.Id, Owners.Id
```

**and**

```
SELECT     Contacts.Id, count(Builders.Id) AS [Builder Count]
FROM       Contacts INNER JOIN Builders ON Contacts.Id = Builders.Id
GROUP BY   Contacts.Id, Builders.Id
```

Since both select statements have the Contact.Id in common, I'd like to see the result displayed as:

```
Contact Id | Owner Count | Builder Count |
   3043    |     1       |       2       |
   4011    |     null    |       1       |
   4045    |     null    |       null    |
   5011    |     4       |       null    |
```

I've tried some variations, with the closest I got being a UNION that ended up displaying two separate rows for each Contact Id, one row for the Owner and the other for the Builder instead of being combined into one row.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just join them on the contact id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Left Outer Join`:

```
Select a.Id, b.[Owner Count], c.[Builder Count]
From
(
    SELECT Id From Contacts
)a Left Outer Join 
(
    SELECT     Contacts.Id, count(Owners.Id) AS [Owner Count]
    FROM       Contacts INNER JOIN Owners ON Contacts.Id = Owners.Id
    GROUP BY   Contacts.Id, Owners.Id
) b On a.Id = b.Id Left Outer Join 
(
    SELECT     Contacts.Id, count(Builders.Id) AS [Builder Count]
    FROM       Contacts INNER JOIN Builders ON Contacts.Id = Builders.Id
    GROUP BY   Contacts.Id, Builders.Id
) c on a.Id = c.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need doing `LEFT JOIN` of both `Owners` and `Builders` to `Contacts`

```
SELECT Contacts.Id,
    count(Owners.Id) AS [Owner Count],
    count(Builders.Id) AS [Builder Count]
FROM Contacts
    LEFT JOIN Owners ON Contacts.Id = Owners.Id
    LEFT JOIN Builders ON Contacts.Id = Builders.Id
GROUP BY Contacts.Id
```

Comment: Unfortunately this direct query seems to double up the counts. E.g.  Owner Count 2 and Builder Count 3 ends up showing a result of Owner Count 6 and Builder Count 6.